# How to handle Enable Editing with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-access

I have very limited PowerShell experience and have searched this site as well as Googled for answer before asking...

I have a PowerShell script which will be used to update MS Access front-end by:

- opening the front-end,
- running a function which returns whether the current version number is the same as the latest version number
- if it needs to be updated, Access is closed and is overwritten

Where I am having difficulty is when I reopen Access and I get the *enable editing* yellow bar, Access shuts down and an error message shows up in PowerShell right before it closes down. This is the message:

```
At C:\Launcher.ps1:33 char:1
+ $condition = $access.run("VersionChecker")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException
```

I should also mention that if I run this step-by-step (F11 - step into) in the PowerShell IDE, I can get through the script with no problems.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the script:

```
##Returns True if an upgrade is required
function OAccess {
    $access = new-object -ComObject access.application
    $access.Visible=$true
    $access.opencurrentdatabase($DBPath)
    ##If the DB's content has not been enabled, an error will occur
    try
    {
        return $access.run("VersionChecker")    
    }
    catch 
    {
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Veuillez cliquer sur le bouton activer le contenu et appuyer sur OK.','Continuer ?',[System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::OK,[System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Exclamation)
        return $false
    }
}

If (OAccess -eq $true) {
    write-host ""
    write-host "Installation de la nouvelle version en cours ..."
    $access.Quit()
    copy-item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Force
    OAccess
}
```

Comment: I don't have a version checker function so I can't test. 2 things though, your function Oaccess should have `Param ($DBPath)` and be called somewhat like this `If ((OAccess -DBPath $Params.DBPath) -eq $true) {` . It currently do not have $dbpath passed down to it so it will definitely create problems at some point. Also, if your function is meant to return $true/$false, you should send the message box output to `|Out-Null` otherwise it will return a non boolean response (eg: Ok / False will be returned)

Comment: I don't think there is something specific to do exactly that but you could add the destination location in the access Trusted locations. Technically, that could be done with Powershell by adding the correct registry key here: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations`. A trusted location mean that any files in that folder won't have the macros disabled by default.